# Is this process possible with an excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

[image]I'm trying to create a sort of excel formula

1.) Go within a Table
2.) Identify all rows that contain “Specific first name” & “ Specific last name”
3.) Then, from those previously identified rows, identify if those rows also contain “Dental”
4.) If the row does contain “Dental” take the appropriate cell in THAT row that contains the dental amount, ( because the dental amount is not the cell directly after/to the right of the the cell that contains dental.

First name and last name will be cell references.

If I can create this formula, I plan to create a Macro that places this formula in the proper cells

Comment: I just posted an example of my desired result. @T.M. I am reviewing your suggestion

Comment: @T.M. your comment helped I had this idea of making a helper column and concatenating to make the Vlookup possible. This worked so this is great progress towards my goal.

Comment: You can FILTER on multiple data with something like; `Filter(array, (criteria1=name1)*(criteria2=name2))` then use XLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH with OFFSET

Comment: @SageMulkey- did you give soln below a go?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hTf_TKmroks5VePW?e=MWy257)/screenshot(s) refer:

<Response structured as follows: M1(a/b) sum/count followed by M2 (sum/count resp.).

---

***M1** -- utilises 'Filter approach' recommended in commentary (@Tragamor) - will explore this first - per screenshot, M1 (cell O6):*

NB: requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel (see M2 for different approach in this regard)...

[image: M1(a) - sum]

```
=LET(q_,FILTER(Table1,--ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld0_type]&"*",Table3[Dental assoc.],0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld2_Name]&"*",Table2[Names],0))),COUNT(INDEX(q_,,MATCH("*"&"cost"&"*",Table1[#Headers],0))))
```

*Noting length may seem cumbersome but mainly attributable to field/table referencing preferences/convention (and dynamism)*
Analogous count (P6) is provided for on similar basis/formulation:

**note omission RE: index 'row' argument -- purposeful as this (or 0 for that matter) generally returns all rows from data in question.

---

[image: M1(a) - count]

```
=LET(q_,FILTER(Table1,--ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld0_type]&"*",Table3[Dental assoc.],0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld2_Name]&"*", Table2[Names],0))),COUNT(1*ISNUMBER(INDEX(q_,,MATCH("*"&"cost"&"*",Table1[#Headers],0)))))
```

**M1(b)** - outside of scope per commentary provided (screenshot above).

---

**M2** - Absconds from filter method (CELL o8 as in 'oscar 8'):

[image: M2 - sum]

```
=SUM(Table1[Fld 3_cost]*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld0_type]&"*",Table3[Dental assoc.],0))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Fld2_Name],Table2[Names],0))))
```

---

Likewise, we have analogous 'count' record (cell p10):

[image: M2 - count]

```
=COUNT(1*(Table1[Fld 3_cost]*ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Table1[Fld0_type]&"*",Table3[Dental assoc.],0))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Fld2_Name],Table2[Names],0)))))
```

---

**Notes:**

Wildcard '*' in match functions (i.e. 'Tom' will match with Tomas (weird spelling for that name, normally has 'h' in it but all the same☺)